# Need to set options parameter value in mapping for the LKM in odi 12c using java

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

We want to dynamically set an option value for mapping for LKM using Java code.
We are checking the datatype column position in table\target datastore and want to set the column position as option parameter for the mapping in LKM.
So we can retrieve the position value in the LKM and do the corresponding action.

Answer (score 0):

We changed the column order on the model level and it got picked in the LKM and IKM.